# Configure contact email and contact email in chrome web store

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, chrome-web-store

I can't publish my chrome extension because it says "You must provide a contact email before you can publish any item. Enter your contact email on the Account tab.
You must verify your contact email before you can publish any item. Begin the verification process on the Account tab."

I entered my E-Mail Address but it still does not work. Does anyone know how to configure that?

I published extensions successfully in the past, but apparently there was a policy change.

Here is the error message:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSdk4.png)

And i have add a backup email it's dosen't work